# Multiple user owning a directory in Linux

Tags: ubuntu

I have 2 users www-data & ubun who needs to own a particular directory /opt/sw/vam

How can I set the access accordingly?

I did this - 
`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/sw/vam` and now ubun cannot access the folders..

How do I give both the users permission..

Comment: There can only be one owner. Use access control lists to give additional permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Either create a group they can share, give that group the perms they need, and set it as the group for the directory or use ACLs as Barmar suggested. I've personally never used ACLs and since groups are more natural in *nix, I would go with the group method. But ACLs would work.

You could to this by:

```
sudo groupadd [group name]
sudo usermod -a -G [group name] www-data
sudo usermod -a -G [group name] ubun
sudo chown -R [whichever]:[group name] /opt/sw/vam
```

Then you need to give set the group permissions like you have the user permissions now. Probably everything, so `sudo chmod -R g+a /opt/sw/vam`.

The `[whichever]` can refer to either user, since it won't matter because they will both be in the group and get the permissions given to the group.

Comment: I tried this it works except the last line...sudo chown -R [whichever]:[group name] /opt/sw/vam...I created a group called optaccess.added 2 users..www-data and ubun....When I do sudo chown -R ubuntu:optaccess /opt/sw/vam...it picks access to the last user..not both